# OpenMP: Prefix Sum Algorithm

Tags: c, openmp

**I'm trying to implement a Prefix Sum Algorithm in C using OpenMP, and I'm stuck.**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int p = 5;
    int X[5] = { 1, 5, 4, 2, 3 };
    int* Y = (int*)malloc(p * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        printf("%d ", X[i]);
    printf("\n");

    Y[0] = X[0];

    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (i = 1; i < p; i++)
        Y[i] = X[i - 1] + X[i];

    int k = 2;
    while (k < p)
    {
        int i;
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (i = k; i < p; i++)
            Y[i] = Y[i - k] + Y[i];
        k += k;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        printf("%d ", Y[i]);
    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**What this code should do?**

> *Input* numbers are in `X`, 
>   *output* numbers are (prefixes) in `Y` 
>   and the *number count* is `p`.

`X = 1, 5, 4, 2, 3`

**Stage I.**

```c
Y[0] = X[0];
```

> `Y[0] = 1`

**Stage II.**

```c
int i;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for (i = 1; i < p; i++)
    Y[i] = X[i - 1] + X[i];
```

Example:

> `Y[1] = X[0] + X[1] = 6`
>   `Y[2] = X[1] + X[2] = 9`
>   `Y[2] = X[2] + X[3] = 6`
>   `Y[4] = X[3] + X[4] = 5`

**Stage III.**  *(where I am stuck)*

```c
int k = 2;
while (k < p)
{
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = k; i < p; i++)
        Y[i] = Y[i - k] + Y[i];
    k += k;
}
```

Example:

> `k = 2`
>   `Y[2] = Y[0] + Y[2] = 1 + 9 = 10`
>   `Y[3] = Y[1] + Y[3] = 6 + 6 = 12`
>   `Y[4] = Y[2] + Y[4] = 10 + 5 = 15`

**Above the `10 + 5 = 15` should be `9 + 5 = 14`, but the `Y[2]` was overwritten by another thread. I want to use that `Y[2]` what was before the for-loop started.**

Example:

> `k = 4`
>   `Y[4] = Y[0] + Y[4] = 1 + 15 = 16`

*Result:* `1, 6, 10, 12, 16`. *Expected good result:* `1, 6, 10, 12, 15`.

Comment: If you have an OpenMP 5.0 compiler then you don't need to do any of this since OpenP 5.0 has the "scan" directive... (Section 2.9.6 on p132 of the standard, which you can download from http://openmp.org if you follow your nose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Above the `10 + 5 = 15` should be `9 + 5 = 14`, but the `Y[2]` was overwritten by another thread. I want to use that `Y[2]` what was before the for-loop started.

With OpenMP, you always have to consider whether your code is correct for the serial case, with a single thread, because

1. It might in fact run that way, and
2. If it's incorrect serially, then it's virtually certain to be incorrect as a parallel program, too.

Your code is not correct serially.  It appears you could fix that by running the problem loop backward, from `i` = `p - 1` to `k`, but in fact that's not sufficient for parallel operation.

Your best bet appears to be to accumulate your partial results into a different array than holds the results of the previous cycle.  For example, you might flip between `X` and `Y` as data source and result, with a little pointer wrangling to grease the iterative wheels.  Or you might do it a little more easily by using a 2D array instead of separate X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE for Stage III.**

```c
int num_threads = 8;
int k = 2;
while (k < p)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for ordered num_threads(k < num_threads ? 1 : num_threads)
    for (i = p - 1; i >= k; i--)
    {
        Y[i] = Y[i - k] + Y[i];
    }
    k += k;
}
```

The code above solved my problem. It's now working with parallel, except the first few round.